# Opening view in a new window in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap

How do I Open a View in a New Window on click of Sitemap Node to which it is mapped.
for example:

```
     <siteMapNode title="Search"  controller="Search" action="Index" localizationResource=""  authorizationResource=""/>
```

How do I open 'Index' View in New Window on click of Search item? Right now its opening in the same Window.I tried using `target = "_blank"` but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery. Give the sitemap nodes a class

```
$('.mapNode').click(function(){
  var url = '/' + $(this).attr("controller") + '/' + $(this).attr("action");
  window.open(url);
  return false;
});
```